# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found

Tags: xml, xsd

My Schema is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="Details">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="create_Date" type="xs:date" maxOccurs="1" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

XML document:

```
<Details xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<create_date>2009-06-04</create_date>
</Details>
```

I am getting the exception as 
XML Document has Error:true cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'create_date'. One of '{create_Date}' is expected.

Please somebody can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML is case-sensitive.

You need to use `create_Date` like you defined it.